# Firefox not recognising json array returned, chrome does

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm making a query to the database and the query is successfull. I create an array where I put the values of the result of the query and then I return the json_encode of the array.

```
     $i=0;
   while($row=$result->fetch()){
     $Invoices[$i]=Array("InvoiceNo"=>$row['InvoiceNo'],"InvoiceDate"=>$row['InvoiceDate'],"CompanyName"=>$row['CompanyName'],"GrossTotal"=>$row['GrossTotal']);
     $i++;
   }
    if($i==0)
    echo json_encode($empty_array);
   else
     echo json_encode($Invoices);
```

This works in google chrome, I have the json viewer and it formats correctly, but in firefox it doesn't show as json. And when I try to parse it it doesn't work. Tried with $.Ajax and $.getJSON

Comment: To make FireFox display it as JSON as well, you should set the proper headers: `Content-Type: application/json`. This will make IE download it as a file, though.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can always try to set the content type using a `header()` call, add the following to the top of the page, before any output:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

You should also make sure that you don't have any empty space before you're actual php code because that will also be sent in the result and may interfere with your json response.

In the ajax call you can set the `dataType` to `json` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"<example.com/index.php>",
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(e) {
     // e now should contain your json data
  }
);
```

Note that:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Yes, it did work, but what about the problem of not being able to parse it?

Comment: @user2466704 - What do you mean you can't parse it?